# [windows-application] tag seems useless

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

A suggested edit recently wanted to add [windows-application](/questions/tagged/windows-application) to a question.

There are 101 questions currently tagged [windows-application](/questions/tagged/windows-application), but I can't imagine what it provides that [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) doesn't satisfy. (Maybe it serves as contrast against [windows-device-driver](/questions/tagged/windows-device-driver) or [windows-kernel](/questions/tagged/windows-kernel) but since neither of those exist yet, the need cannot be great.)

Is there a reason for this tag? Is this a candidate for a merge request? Or trogdor?

Comment: Similarly, the [`application`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application) tag seems to be completely useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a funny story: I was just in the middle of writing a "I definitely think that it should be merged with the [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) tag" answer, when I clicked on the tag and realized that [I'd already proposed that tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows/synonyms).

No wonder I agree with it! If you *also* agree with it, please vote for the tag synonym.

Comment: Looks like someone beat me to the vote :)